# "the only one of + plural noun" = singular or plural verb? (focus on the only)

Tags: verb-agreement

He is one of the candidates who is/are willing to debate the issues. (it is 'are' due to the relative pronoun)
He is the **only** one of the candidates who is/are willing to debate the issues. (what should be used here?)
I am focusing on "only" here.If we go by 'only' then its a single noun but if we go by the relative pronoun rule then who refers to candidates and that calls for a plural verb. I need to know this strictly in terms of grammar please.